# htaccess rewriting dynamic urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic

How can I rewrite this url

`http://www.example.com/index.php?test=<some dynamic data>`

to

```
http://www.example.com/<some dynamic data>
```

I have tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index.php?test=(\w+)?$ $1
```

although it doesn't work.

How can this be done? And is it still possible for example to do `echo $_GET['test']` with the rewritten url(or anything with the query)?

Comment: The notion of "renaming" doesn't make any sense in this context. Mod_rewrite is in the middle of 2 things, the client (browser) who is resolving a URL as a location of a resource, and the server which takes a request for a resource and maps it to the actual resource. These 2 things are different. Mod_rewrite can only take what the client requests and process that before the server tries to map it to the resource. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to remove index.php?test=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the incoming url in the browser is the dynamic one:

```
http://www.example.com/<some dynamic data>
```

and you're trying to rewrite it to this, for your code:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?test=<some dynamic data>
```

then try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?test=$1 [NC,L]
```

The last line takes anything that comes in, and sends it to index.php with the test parameter. The RewriteCond is making sure it doesn't do this with index.php itself, or it would be an infinite loop.

If you're trying to go the other way, and have your code create dynamic urls for displaying on your site, then that's somewhere else in your website code, wherever you're creating your html. Once created, this rule will rewrite them back to index.php.